# How to disable Year/Month navigation in Angular UI Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm wondering if any knows how to disable the month/year navigation button on the Angular UI datepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

We want to disable the ability for users to click on the "Month/Year" text in between the navigation arrows and can't figure it out.

[image]

Our current config options look like this:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yyyy'",
        'starting-day': 0,
        'show-weeks': false
    };
```

Our html looks like this:

```
<span datepicker-popup="shortDate" ng-model="currentDate" is-open="isDatePickerOpen" datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" ng-click="openDatePicker($event)"></span>
```

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the max-mode property and set it to day and will disable that button.

```
<datepicker max-mode="day" ng-model="dt"></datepicker>
```

Have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/5I8QQiI3dLvOpyDjd2fk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

How about just using css to remove the buttons from the ui?

```
.date-picker-button { display: none; }
```

Note: I do not know which selector to use, its just an example. You'll have to inspect the element to see what the actual selector is